# ¿Cómo rotar el texto en un grafico usando ggplotly?

Tags: r, plotly, ggplot

Tengo el siguiente df de ejemplo:

```
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)

iris_plot = iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(valor = sum(Sepal.Length))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Species    valor
  <fct>      <dbl>
1 setosa      250.
2 versicolor  297.
3 virginica   329.
```

y ademas un grafico usando ggplot

```
p = iris_plot %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Species, y = valor, fill = valor)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
  geom_text(aes(label = valor),
            angle = 90)
```

Con el parámetro `angle = 90` el texto de cada barra rota 90 grados, pero al usar `ggplotly`,
se pierde la rotación

```
ggplotly(p)
```

Como podria hacerlo usando ggplotly?

Me imagino que debe ser algo como:

```
ggplotly(p) %>%
  add_text(text = list(textangle = 90))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ggplotly` lamentablemente a la fecha tiene un "issue" con respecto al ángulo de los `geom_text()` en lo que parece que directamente lo ignora (ver [aquí](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/issues/953) y [aquí](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/issues/709)). Efectivamente una posible solución es hacer algo parecido directamente en `plotly`, pero no con el `add_text()` que no maneja el ajuste de la orientación sino con `add_annotations()`:

```
p <- iris_plot %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Species, y = valor, fill = valor)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity')

p <- ggplotly(p)

p = add_annotations(p,
                 x = as.numeric(iris_plot$Species),
                 y = iris_plot$valor,
                 text = iris_plot$valor,
                 textangle =90
                )

p
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona perfecto

Comment: una ultima consulta, si tengo la barra ordenada de mayor a menor, es decir, aes(
    x = reorder(Species, -valor),
    y = valor,
    fill = valor
  ) como debo usar el add_annotations?

Comment: Lo que deberías hacer es reordenar el factor Species en los datos directamente y no en el mapping. Por ejemplo:  `iris_plot$Species = fct_reorder(iris_plot$Species, iris_plot$valor)` con esto el código tal como está en la respuesta debería funcionar.